# How to exclude sitemesh filter when resolving error in spring?

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I have a Sitemesh filter that will decorate pages. I have configured a Spring's `exceptionResolver` so that all the error will go to a view called `error` which is then pointed to `WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp` through `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

Now the error page is decorated by sitemesh and I would like to exclude it from decoration. Using `<exclude>` tag of sitemesh `decorator.xml` does not work. Because the incoming url may be something as normal as `/app/login.html` and sitemesh already catch it and decorate it.

I notice that in Spring if I have a `@ResponseBody` for ajax request, it would by pass Sitemesh's decoration. I wonder how it works? Can I make something in the `errorResolver` to bypass sitemesh also?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by imlementing own `exceptionResolver`, streaming output manually and return null `ModelAndView`

```
public class MyExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver{
public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {

    //other things like logging...
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp");
    try {
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in SiteMesh 3 this type of exclude works (sitemesh3.xml)

```
<sitemesh>
  <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>

  <mapping path="/*" decorator="/WEB-INF/sitemesh/decorator.jsp" />
  <mapping path="/app/login.html" exclude="true"/>

</sitemesh>
```

This is tried in Spring 3. I hope this helped you.

Comment: How come it's 'exclue' instead of 'exclude' ?

Comment: The original programmer didn't used spell checker, and now thet makes confusion :)

Comment: The documentation is incorrect but you can see the attribute is exclude in the schema at https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh3/blob/master/sitemesh/src/main/resources/org/sitemesh/sitemesh3.xsd