# Remove decorator from error page

Tags: spring, sitemesh

We use sitemesh for decorations on our website. We have an error page and we would not like to apply the decorator to it. The error page comes up in case an exception occurs (we hope rarely), not for 404, that's another page.

The error page is called through a spring controller and is defined in web.xml as follows:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/view/errorpage/display</location>
</error-page>
```

Sitemesh configuration in `web.xml` is as follows:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And finally, the error controller is excluded in `decorators.xml` as follows:

```
<excludes>
    <pattern>/view/errorpage*</pattern>
</excludes>
```

But this doesn't do the trick, since the decorator page is still being applied to the error page. Is there something I am missing out please?

Thanks!

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

This provided my answer:

[How to exclude sitemesh filter when resolving error in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990598/how-to-exclude-sitemesh-filter-when-resolving-error-in-spring)